# Как заменить все http: на https: в smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

На сайте есть много контентной части, которая заполняется администратором. И в результате мы имеем очень много абсолютных ссылок http. Их всех переписать на https очень долго.

```
{$articleTitle|replace:'Garden':'Vineyard'}
```

Хочу использовать эту функцию, но не знаю как именно нужно получать эти ссылки.
Может кто подскажет?

Comment: А почему администратор не писал относительные ссылки? Почему бы не преобразовать контент из абсолютных ссылок в относительные, зачем smarty приплетать?

Comment: потому что страниц уже очень много

Comment: Если написать скрипт для преобразования контента, то совершенно неважно сколько страниц

Comment: у вас контент-то в базе хранится, или где? там и меняйте